Failed to commission a Matter device to Google Home Sample APP for Matter without Internet
I am trying to commission a Matter over wifi device to GHSAFM APP without any Internet visit, but it always failed:
enter image description here
I check the logcat then found some issue:

04-10 17:06:30.153 28769 28769 I MatterCommissioner: (REDACTED) Resolved %d existing fabric(s).
04-10 17:06:30.153 28769 28769 I MatterCommissioner: Generating device credentials. [CONTEXT service_id=336 ]
04-10 17:06:30.283 28769 28978 W m.vks   : [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
04-10 17:06:30.284  1392  1906 W BestClock: java.time.DateTimeException: Missing network time fix
04-10 17:06:30.304  1392  1906 W BestClock: java.time.DateTimeException: Missing network time fix
04-10 17:06:30.426 28769 28978 W m.vks   : [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
04-10 17:06:30.442 26050 29299 W adbd    : timed out while waiting for FUNCTIONFS_BIND, trying again
04-10 17:06:30.442 26050 29299 I adbd    : UsbFfs: connection terminated: monitor thread finished
04-10 17:06:30.442 26050 26050 I adbd    : UsbFfs: already offline
04-10 17:06:30.443 26050 26050 I adbd    : destroying transport UsbFfs
04-10 17:06:30.443 26050 26050 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection being destroyed
04-10 17:06:30.494 26050 26054 I adbd    : opening control endpoint /dev/usb-ffs/adb/ep0
04-10 17:06:30.500 26050 26054 I adbd    : UsbFfsConnection constructed
04-10 17:06:30.501 26050 29303 I adbd    : UsbFfs-monitor thread spawned
04-10 17:06:30.584 28769 28800 I RpcRunner: (REDACTED) Retrieving ClientContext and token for %s.
04-10 17:06:30.601 28769 28800 I RpcRunner: (REDACTED) Executing RPC %s
04-10 17:06:30.621 28769 28798 W RpcRunner: Retrying RPC GetCommissioningNonce (attempt 2 of 2) in 2,000 ms. [CONTEXT service_id=336 ]

After I connected to Internet the commission can be done, the log is different:

04-10 17:15:55.414 30437 30437 I MatterCommissioner: (REDACTED) Resolved %d existing fabric(s).
04-10 17:15:55.415 30437 30437 I MatterCommissioner: Generating device credentials. [CONTEXT service_id=336 ]
04-10 17:15:55.830 30437 30470 I RpcRunner: (REDACTED) RPC %s completed successfully.
04-10 17:15:55.833 30437 30437 I MatterCommissioner: Retrieved commissioning nonces. [CONTEXT service_id=336 ]

Does anyone know how to make it possible for Matter offline commissioning?
Matter is an application protocol based on local network, it should be supported offline commissioning and operation.

Everything in Google Home goes through their cloud.  You may be able to use Matter by itself, but if you hook it into Google Home, you need internet.

As of today, one does need a working internet connection to commission matter devices. There is no provision of doing the commissioning without internet as of today.
